# different grunt watch tasks and triggering events

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I try to use two watch tasks, one for html and css which (should) just trigger a reload (which does not happen either) and another one which is triggered by .js files. In an event I then try to just uglify the file that changed, then concat all the js files. It does not work, all the time all js files are uglifies, no matter which file changes. Being new to Grunt, can somebody please spare a minute or two?

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      files: {
        src: ['js/minified/jquery.min.js',
          'js/minified/jquery-migrate.min.js',
          'js/minified/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js',
          'js/minified/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js',
          'js/minified/video.js',
          'js/minified/bigvideo.js',
          'js/minified/jquery.cycle.all.js',
          'js/minified/jquery.maximage.js',
          'js/minified/jquery.jfeed.js',
          'js/minified/moment.min.js',
          'js/minified/fastclick.js',
          'js/minified/cookies.min.js',
          'js/minified/jquery.hammer.min.js',
          'js/minified/index.js'
        ],
        dest: '<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      },
    },
    uglify: {
      files: {
        src: 'js/*.js', // source files mask
        dest: 'js/minified', // destination folder
        expand: true, // allow dynamic building
        flatten: true, // remove all unnecessary nesting
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      files: ['gruntfile.js', 'js/index.js'],
      options: {
        // options here to override JSHint defaults
        globals: {
          jQuery: true,
          console: true,
          module: true,
          document: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      options: {
        livereload: true
      },
      javascript: {
        files: ['js/*.js', 'gruntfile.js'],
        tasks: ['watchtask'],
        options: {
          nospawn: true,
        }
      },
      therest: {
        files: ['index.html', 'css/*.css'],
        tasks: []
      }
    },
    open: {
      dev: {
        path: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
      },
    },
    connect: {
      server: {
        options: {
          hostname: '*',
          port: 8000
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    //change the source in the uglify task at run time so that it affects the changed file only
    grunt.config(['uglify', 'files', 'src'], filepath);
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'uglify', 'concat', 'connect', 'open', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('watchtask', ['jshint', 'uglify', 'concat']);

};
```

Comment: I do get the following error: `Running "watch" task
Waiting...2013-09-11 22:25 node[10342] (CarbonCore.framework) FSEventStreamFlushSync(): failed assertion '(SInt64)last_id > 0LL'`

Comment: Mac OS 10.8.4, node 0.10.18, grunt 0.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behavior. When any file changes in the `watch:javascript` task file list, the associated tasks are executed. Your `watchtask` runs `uglify` which uglifies all of the JS code. You would need to specify separate watch targets for different JS files and separate uglify targets to do what you suggest.

For example:

```
...
  uglify: {
    someTarget: {
      files: {
        src: 'js/file1.js', // source files mask
        dest: 'js/minified', // destination folder
        expand: true, // allow dynamic building
        flatten: true, // remove all unnecessary nesting
      }
    },
    otherTarget: {
      files: {
        src: 'js/file2.js', // source files mask
        dest: 'js/minified', // destination folder
        expand: true, // allow dynamic building
        flatten: true, // remove all unnecessary nesting
      }
    }
  },
  ...
  watch: {
    options: {
      livereload: true
    },
    javascriptOne: {
  files: ['js/file1.js'],
      tasks: ['uglify:someTarget'],
      options: {
        nospawn: true,
      }
    },
    javascriptTwo: {
      files: ['js/file2.js'],
      tasks: ['uglify:otherTarget'],
      options: {
        nospawn: true,
      }
    },
    ...
  },
...
```

Comment: I do not really get what the problem is with my setup, then. Is it not possible to watch some files and trigger a task to uglify some other files?

Comment: Sort of... a watch task says "when one of these matching files changes, execute this task". So for yours, it says that when any file in the `js` folder with and extension of `.js` is changed, run the `watchtask` - which in turn runs `uglify` and `concat` which I'm guessing uglifies and concatenates _all_ JS files.
If you want to uglify _only_ file X when it is changed, then you would have to watch it alone, and then run a task that only uglifies that one file.

Comment: Of course, you could always try to write a plugin to do what you're asking for, might not even be that hard. ;)